# Looping through JSON object with Alpine JS in Lit 2.0 web component

Tags: javascript, alpine.js, lit

I can't figure out how to loop through the connections object from fetch using x-for and Alpine JS to display the 2 records.

I tried looping through ${this.connections} with x-for but got a "object Object" error.

```
import { LitElement, html } from "../lit-all.min.js";

export class ContentDiv extends LitElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.connections;
    }

    static properties = {
        connections: {},
    };

    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();

        const dbPath = sessionStorage.getItem("dbPath");

        fetch(`${dbPath}/connections/listConnections.php`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((response) => {
                this.connections = response;
            });
    }

    createRenderRoot() {
        return this;
    }

    render() {
        return html`
          <h1>Connections</h1>
          <div>
            <ul>
              ***Loop and display ${this.connections} here***
            </ul>
          </div>
        `;
    }
}

customElements.define("content-div", ContentDiv);
```

Comment: Can I see an example response from `${dbPath}/connections/listConnections.php`?

Comment: Sure. 
`[{connectionId: "12345",connectionName:"first connection},{connectionId: "67890",connectionName:"second connection}]`

Answer (score 0):

Is the the response coming as an array of objects? It seems like that based on your comment.

If so, I'd firstly instantiate `this.connections` as an empty array in the constructor:

```js
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.connections = [];
    }
```

And within render, you can do one of multiple ways of rendering an array in the template.

For instance, with plain JavaScript array method.

```js
    render() {
        return html`
          <h1>Connections</h1>
          <div>
            <ul>
              ${this.connections.map((item) => html`<li>${item.connectionName}</li>`)}
            </ul>
          </div>
        `;
    }
```

You may also use the `map()` built-in directive provided in the lit package.

```js
import { LitElement, html, map } from "../lit-all.min.js";

...

    render() {
        return html`
          <h1>Connections</h1>
          <div>
            <ul>
              ${map(this.connections, (item) => html`<li>${item.connectionName}</li>`)}
            </ul>
          </div>
        `;
    }
```

See https://lit.dev/docs/templates/lists/ for more information.